# Custom Stackstack runner won't lazyload

Tags: python, salt-stack

Creating a custom runner but `salt-run myrunner.test` returns with `Module 'myrunner' is not available.`. 
Here's my versions

`Salt: 2015.5.5
         Python: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
         Jinja2: 2.2.1
       M2Crypto: 0.20.2
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.0.1
        libnacl: 1.4.3
         PyYAML: 3.10
          ioflo: Not Installed
          PyZMQ: 14.3.1
           RAET: Not Installed
            ZMQ: 3.2.5
           Mako: Not Installed
        Tornado: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed`

This is what the logs output when i try running

`2015-09-16 15:08:21,109 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7617] Could not LazyLoad myrunner.test
2015-09-16 15:08:21,111 [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][7617] LazyLoaded nested.output`

Here's the runner code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

# salt imports
import salt.config
import salt.loader
import salt.runner
import salt.client

def __virtual__():
    return 'myrunner'

def test():
    print "Hello World!"
    return True
```

I've also set my `runner_dir` in my master config file to `/srv/salt/_runners`. I can't get salt to recognize my runner. Has anyone else had a similar problem? Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, `runner_dir` is incorrect.
Use this instead:

```
runner_dirs: ['/srv/salt/_runners',]
```

`runner_dirs` is a list of directories the master should look in for runners to execute.

I tested this with your exact runner and it worked for me.